# Flot chart with Threshold and Fillbetween

Tags: flot

I'm looking for advice on how I should/can configure [Flotcharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) using the Fillbetween and Threshold pluggins to create a chart that accomplishes the following:

1. Plot a line chart. (done)
2. Set some threshold values. (done)
3. Set and fill values that are outside of the threshold values. (not quite done)

Here's what I've accomplished so far,

https://jsfiddle.net/gstoa/utv4kvw2/

```
$(function() {
  var values = {
    'avgBottom': [
      [1, -2],
      [2, -2],
      [3, -2],
      [4, -2],
      [5, -2]
    ],
    'avgTop': [
      [1, 3],
      [2, 3],
      [3, 3],
      [4, 3],
      [5, 3]
    ],
    'values': [
      [1, .5],
      [2, -3],
      [3, .8],
      [4, 4.5],
      [5, 6.6]
    ]
  };

  var dataset = [{
    data: values['values'],
    lines: {
      show: true
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)"
  }, {
    id: 'avgBottom',
    data: values['avgBottom'],
    lines: {
      show: true,
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill: false
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)"
  }, {
    id: 'values',
    data: values['values'],
    lines: {
      show: true,
      lineWidth: 0.5,
      fill: 0.2,
      shadowSize: 0
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)",
    fillBetween: 'avgBottom'
  }, {
    id: 'avgTop',
    data: values['avgTop'],
    lines: {
      show: true,
      lineWidth: 0,
      fill: 0.2
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)",
    fillBetween: 'values'
  }];

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, {
    xaxis: {
      tickDecimals: 0
    },
    series: {
      lines: {
        show: true,
        fill: true
      },
      points: {
        show: false,
        radius: 4
      },
      color: "#62CB31",
      //      threshold: {
      //        below: -2,
      //        color: "rgb(255,0,0)"
      //      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      tickFormatter: function(v) {
        return v;
      }
    }
  });

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1, d2, d3]);
});
```

I'd like this line chart to look like the following:
[image]

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I had to switch from the [`fillbetween`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.fillbetween.js) to the [`fillbelow`](https://github.com/whatbox/jquery.flot.fillbelow) flot plugin. I then had to modify the source of the `fillbelow` plugin to look at a new [`fillColor`](https://github.com/prmech/jquery.flot.fillbelow) property of the series (I've got a pull request to merge these changes back into the main branch).

All in all, your new data set looks like the code snippet below ([this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/utv4kvw2/6/) demonstrates how to get the chart to look like your example image).

```
var dataset = [{
    id: 'topValues',
    data: values['values'],
    lines: {
        show: true,
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)",
    fillBelowTo: 'avgTop',
    fillBelowUseSeriesObjectFillColor: false,
    fillColor: "#FF0000"
}, {
    id: 'avgTop',
    data: values['avgTop'],
    lines: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        fill: true
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)"
}, {
    id: 'bottomValues',
    data: values['values'],
    lines: {
    show: true,
    lineWidth: 0,
    shadowSize: 0
    },
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)"
}, {
    id: 'avgBottom',
    data: values['avgBottom'],
    lines: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 0,
        fill: true,
    },
    fillBelowTo: 'bottomValues',
    fillBelowUseSeriesObjectFillColor: false,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    color: "rgb(50,50,255)"
}];
```

- The `fillBelowTo` property acts similarly to the `fillBetween`
  property of the fillbetween plugin - it denotes to which series you'd
  like to fill below to.
- The `fillBelowUseSeriesObjectFillColor`
  property (set to `false`) tells us to not use the `lines.fillColor`
  color and instead use the `fillColor` value. If `fillBelowUseSeriesObjectFillColor` was `true`, the `lines.fillColor` color would be used (which in this case would be blue).

Comment: I'm shedding tears of joy, you are incredible.  Thank you -- this is exactly what I was looking to accomplish!  I only wish I would have saved myself 8 hours of tinkering around and just called for help earlier ;)  Thanks again -- a huge help!